# OSX app store and autologin application

Tags: mac-app-store

In my OSX application I need to be use LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL for autologin application. But I find that

> **2.26** Apps that are set to auto-launch or to have other code automatically run at startup or login without user consent will be rejected

And I worry about what reviewer will say? Maybe somebody encountered with it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to ask the user to allow your app to add itself to autologin. If you don't, Apple will reject your app.

If the user doesn't grant permission for the app to add itself to autostart I would assume that your app still needs to provide (most of its) value to the user, or else it will also not be approved (because the user really has no choice but to add the app to autologin).